# curl deployment of versioned war on Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, curl

I'm trying to deploy a versioned war on Tomcat.

As many of you may probably know, there is a load balancer in Tomcat that will redirect all new session on the newest version of the war\app, you just need to put the version after two `##` (example: `mywar##1.0.1.war`)

I'm successfully deploying with curl:

```
curl -T "MyApp##001.war" https://${username}:${password}@${host}/manager/text/deploy?path=/MyApp&update=true"
```

However, once deployed I can't find version!

I've tried all possible combinations after `-T` and after `path=/`, is this a bug or is there a way I can't do it with curl?

I'd like to use Tomcat Manager instead of putting the war inside `/webapps` because this script would be fully compliant to our security policies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are simply missing the `version` parameter:

```
$ curl -T "MyApp##001.war" "https://${username}:${password}@${host}/manager/text/deploy?path=/MyApp&update=true&version=001"
```

Without the "version" parameter, Tomcat doesn't know you are trying to do parallel deployment. In fact, you probably deployed a version-less WAR with your original command.

You might think that `curl` has somehow sent the filename (`MyApp##001.war`) to Tomcat and that Tomcat should detect the version-number from the filename and use that, but you would be wrong. `curl` only sends the filename if the URL (path) ends with a `/` character. In that case, `curl` will actually append the filename to the end of the URL and use that to contact the server (and it won't work).